# ¿Cuál es el origen de "meapilas"?

Tags: etimología, españa, insultos

Existe en España el insulto *meapilas* para referirse a alguien afectado, frágil, no del todo claro entre lo que dice sobre la moral y lo que acaba haciendo:

> Juan es un ***meapilas***: se pasa el día pidiendo a la gente que sea buena pero luego es incapaz de ayudar a una viejecita a cruzar la calle.

El DLE recoge:

> [**meapilas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OhvYTiL)
>   De *mear* y *pila*<sup>2</sup>.
>   1. m. santurrón.

Que a su vez nos lleva a *mear* como sinónimo de *orinar* (¡o [*peer*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22556/1674)!) y:

> [**santurrón, na**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XGaXdaq)
>   Del despect. de *santo*.
>   1. adj. Exagerado en los actos de devoción. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Gazmoño, hipócrita que aparenta ser devoto. U. t. c. s.
>
> [**pila<sup>2</sup>**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sz7PRrG)
>   Del lat. pila 'mortero'.
>   1. f. Pieza grande de piedra o de otra materia, cóncava y profunda, donde cae o se echa el agua para varios usos.
>   2. f. Pieza de piedra, cóncava, con su pedestal de la misma materia, y tapa de madera, que hay en las iglesias parroquiales para administrar el sacramento del bautismo.
>   3. f. Parroquia o feligresía.

Pero claro, la imagen que nos acaba generando es la de alguien que orina en una pila bautismal, que es algo bastante más *hooliganizado* que el disloque puramente moral de quien así se define.

Por todo ello, me pregunto: ¿cuál es el origen de meapilas? ¿Se usa fuera de España? ¿Es correcta la definición que di inicialmente del término?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encuentro dos casos en el CORDE, pero uno no me deja muy claro el significado de la palabra. El otro creo que sí:

> *24 diciembre, sábado*
>
> *¡Que no, puchas! ¡Que esto no es la Nochebuena! Aunque el torda del tío se emperre que es mejor que aquello. Pero, como yo le digo, de qué, tío, sí no hay cosa con cosa. Que me diga que esto es como la noche San Juan allá, pase, pero de lo otro, ni hablar. Una cerveza aquí, una horchata allá, un trago en el otro sitio, que no son formas, vamos. Luego los belenes, si les pones nieve, mal; si les pones calor, peor. Uno, mal que bien, tiene sus creencias y de esta manera parece como que todo fuese una coña. Y no es que uno sea un meapilas, pero las cosas serias, serias son y no hay por qué menearlas.*
>
> Miguel Delibes, "Diario de un emigrante", 1958 (España).

Por el contexto yo diría que *meapilas* se refiere a un *santurrón* en el sentido de "devoto exagerado". Entiendo que este significado de *meapilas* pudo originarse por la idea de que alguien pueda pasar tanto tiempo en la iglesia que no tenga más remedio que hacer sus necesidades donde le pille con tal de no abandonarla.

Por si no queda claro, en el CREA hay casos más recientes que insisten en ese significado:

> *Dice Emilio: -Enfermo me pone esto de Castilla Imperial. Aquí en Taranco, en el valle, es donde por primera vez apareció la palabra Castilla. Fue en el acta fundacional del monasterio. Pues aquí lo vienen a celebrar unos tipos cultos, gente del Opus, los Satunotes les llaman, y hablan de lo castellano y le dan varapalo a la cultura del calimocho. Pero lo cojonudo es que vinieron también los comuneros y, coño, los dos iban por lo castellano, la identidad y estas cosas, pero salieron echando pestes, que ellos eran izquierdistas y los otros, meapilas.*
>
> La Vanguardia, 16/05/1995.

Ahí directamente está llamando *meapilas* a la gente del Opus, entiendo nuevamente que en su sentido de "devoto exagerado". Por lo que creo que tu idea inicial del significado de la palabra puede estar equivocada.

En todo caso, el problema veo que está en las dos definiciones de *santurrón*: yo he estado haciendo alusión a la primera acepción, pero tiene una segunda que sí que describe tu idea inicial. Y dado que la redirección de *meapilas* a *santurrón* no especifica a cuál de las dos acepciones de esta se refiere, la gente la puede usar como indicas, en plan despectivo y significando "hipócrita".

Veo en el blog de *Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe* que [hay una entrada sobre esta palabra](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-surge-la-expresion-ser-un-meapilas/):

> Comenzó a utilizarse el término ‘meapilas’ para referirse a aquellos beatos de misa y confesión diaria, ya que se creía que de tanto ir a la iglesia y persignarse con el agua bendita acabarían orinándola.

Esta interpretación desde luego es más respetuosa y menos hereje: no es que mees en las pilas, sino lo que hay en las pilas. Y aclara que, efectivamente, en los últimos años está virando el significado hacia lo que tú comentas:

> Desde un tiempo a esta parte se le cambió el sentido original y es frecuente escuchar la expresión ‘ese es un meapilas’ con la intención de *señalar la poca importancia del mismo e indicar que está falto de personalidad*.

Aunque indica que este cambio no se sabe a ciencia cierta cuándo tuvo lugar. Incide también en este origen "El Gran Libro de los Insultos", de Pancracio Celdrán (publicado en 2008):

> Es voz compuesta en la que el término pila alude a la del agua bendita situada a la entrada del templo y usada para persignarse o santiguarse quien entra en el lugar sagrado. Por otro lado, el verbo mear está empleado en sentido figurado: lo que mea el santurrón es el agua bendita de tanto tomarla.

Define además este libro la palabra *meapilas* como:

> Santurrón, beato; measalves o persona hipócrita que se da golpes en el pecho y entona el *Yo pecador*, pero cuya conducta no está a la altura de su pretendida piedad.

Lo cual incide también en la variante *hipócrita* de la palabra.

En cuanto al ámbito temporal, el primer caso que encuentro en el CORDE es el mencionado de 1958. No encuentro casos en la hemeroteca de la BNE pero sí en la del periódico ABC, [siendo el primero de 1967](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/1967/10/21/076.html):

> Quienes suelen pensar que los hombres de Acción Católica o de las demás organizaciones apostólicas son -lo que en un lenguaje muy vulgar y con perdón-, suele llamarse meapilas, santurrones preocupados de sus devociones, pero desenganchados de los dolores del mundo, se hubieran llevado un buen chasco asistiendo a esta Asamblea.

Curioso que este texto nos explica que las dos acepciones de *santurrón* no son tan diferentes: si eres un *meapilas* eres un devoto tan exagerado que pierdes el vínculo con la realidad y no aplicas tu *santidad* hacia los demás. Siguiendo con la línea temporal, comentar que el Ngram nos da un caso anterior, de 1949, correspondiente a un ejemplar de la *Revista de dialectología y tradiciones populares*, haciendo referencia a los apodos que se usan en la provincia de Burgos:

> VILLADIEGO - *Meapilas*. Los de los pueblos inmediatos les cantan la copla siguiente: Cuando sale la luna / sale el lucero / salen los meapilas / de Villadiego.

Antes de esta fecha no encuentro nada por ninguna parte, así que ignoro hacia cuándo pudo ser el origen de la expresión en su forma oral.

Para concluir, comentar que todos los casos encontrados tanto en el CORDE (2) como en el CREA (29) como en el CORPES (40) son todos de España, por lo que parece poco probable que la expresión haya pasado a América.

Comment: Para terminar de responder solo falta aclarar si se usa o no fuera de España y mi pequeño aporte es que por lo menos en Colombia no.

Comment: @DGaleano tienes toda la razón, se me pasó esa parte. Pero sí, tiene pinta de ser un término relativamente reciente y que no ha salido de España. De hecho los casos encontrados por el CREA (29) son todos de aquí. He añadido esta información a la respuesta.

Comment: Había colocado una respuesta pero ya estaba casi todo dicho. Agrego acá esta otra referencia: "... Meapilas, una verdadera rareza de nuestro léxico, ya que su significado, persona gazmoña (otra maravilla de adjetivo) de exagerada y ostentosa devoción, contrasta con la imagen que recoge, ya que el acto de orinar sobre el agua bendita resulta clara y agresivamente blasfemo." `[Breve guía del improperio](http://episcophagus.blogspot.com.co/2010/08/breve-guia-del-improperio-iv.html)